# Confusion about Wall-sun-sun primes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_congruences

$691$ is mentioned as the smallest Wall-sun-sun prime although no Wall-sun-sun prime is known. Apparently, this is a typo.

> Does anyone have an idea how this typo could emerge ? Is there a property that $691$ has which could have led to this typo ?

Comment: 691 does not appear on the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall%E2%80%93Sun%E2%80%93Sun_prime so presumably this is a misunderstanding

Comment: And $F_{690} \equiv 105032 \bmod {691^2}$ rather than $0$ so it fails the assertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have been confused with the first [Lychrel number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number), which is $196$ with its associated palimdrom prime $691$. But this is pure speculation. See sequence A023108 in OEIS.

Comment: Well possible (+1)